# How to disable a button on an XSL stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, xslt, button, infopath

I'm trying to disable a button via an XSL stylesheet (for a form on InfoPath 2010), but I don't want the button to change appearance or be grayed out, just remove the click "animation" and make it static. Can it be done?

I've tried messing with the HTML but with no effects:

```
<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
```

Sample code:

```
</input>  <input title="" class="langFont" style="CURSOR: pointer; FONT-SIZE: small; TEXT-DECORATION: ; BORDER-TOP: #ffffff 4.5pt; HEIGHT: 33px; BORDER-RIGHT: #ffffff 3pt solid; WIDTH: 100px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #ffffff 3pt solid; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #ffffff; MARGIN: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: #ffffff 3pt solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #002060" size="9" type="button" xd:CtrlId="CTRL26" xd:xctname="Button" tabIndex="0">
<xsl:if test="function-available('xdXDocument:GetDOM')">
<xsl:attribute name="value">
<xsl:value-of select="xdXDocument:GetDOM(&quot;OrganizationChartPeople- שם ותפקיד&quot;)/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Title[../d:ID = 14]"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<button type="button" disabled="disabled">Click Me!</button>
```

HTML allows such attributes to be written in abbreviated form; XML does not.